# Unable to import interface from models.ts

Tags: typescript

I am unable to import interface named  Chat in chats.ts file from models.ts       file.

---

chat.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import * as moment from 'moment';
import { Chat, MessageType } from 'api/models';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'chats.html'
})
export class ChatsPage {
    chats: Observable<Chat[]>;

    constructor() {
        this.chats = this.findChats();
    }
}
```

---

models.ts

```
export enum MessageType {
    TEXT = <any>'text'
}

export interface Chat {
    _id?: string;
    title?: string;
    picture?: string;
    lastMessage?: Message;
}

export interface Message{
    _id?: string;
    chatId?: string;
    content?: string;
    createdAt?: Date;
    type?: MessageType
}
```

I was able to import MessageType without any error but for Chat it is showing name not found eror.

Comment: don't we need to know what `Model.ts` looks like to answer this?

Comment: I have mentioned it - models.ts

Comment: including the error message might help with debugging this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to include the `Message` interface to import. The name not found error could be caused by the missing `Message` interface being used in the `Chat` interface.

Comment: I had included Message interface in import but the error was same.Now along with that error following error has occurred                                                                                             Typescript Error:1127
Invalid character.
declarations.d.ts

!<symlink>��../src/declarations.d.ts